# Tensorflow Lite - ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

This is probably going to be a stupid question but I am new to machine learning and Tensorflow.
I am trying to run object detection API on Raspberry Pi using **Tensorflow Lite**. I am trying to modify my code with the help of this example

```
https://github.com/freedomtan/tensorflow/blob/deeplab_tflite_python/tensorflow/contrib/lite/examples/python/object_detection.py
```

This piece of code will detect object from a image. But instead of a image I want to detect object on real time through Pi camera.
I tried to modified this code to read input from camera instead of image. Here is my piece of code -

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import interpreter as interpreter_wrapper
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, image_np = cap.read()

PATH_TO_MODEL = "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.tflite"

interpreter = tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter(model_path=PATH_TO_MODEL)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

while True:
  # NxHxWxC, H:1, W:2
  height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
  width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]
  ret, image_np = cap.read()

  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  #if floating_model:
  image_np_expanded = (np.float32(image_np_expanded) - input_mean) / input_std

  #HERE I AM GETTING ERROR
  interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], image_np_expanded)

  if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

but I am getting this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "New_object_detection.py", line 257, in <module>
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], image_np_expanded)
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/interpreter.py", line 151, in set_tensor
    self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py", line 133, in SetTensor
    return _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper_SetTensor(self, i, value)
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this error or suggest a tutorial for the same?

Comment: I am not familiar with  `cv2.VideoCapture(0)'s` output. I guess the error message you got already told you what to do: check the dimensions of what the model expects and what you feed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, you are right. I had to modify the size on my input tensor before feeding it to the model. It was a silly mistake.
This line of code fixed my issue.
`image_np = cv2.resize(image_np, (height, width))`

Answer (score 0):

Many image-based machine learning models are trained with fixed-sized inputs. The original image may come with different dimensions, but get resized to a fixed size (e.g. 224x224x3).

Therefore, you need to resize the image before feeding the input to the model. It may work well because the fact that the training data are also resized from various sizes.

As the comment above already pointed out, `cv.resize` can do the trick.

Comment: I had the same issue above and i'm doing noramlization of the images (including resizing to proper size) and yet keep getting this same error